# Keep modal displayed when I click submit

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to create a sign in - signup form, using html `<form>` and bootstrap4 modal. Every thing is okay but when I click the submit button, the modal is dismissed, so the error of data validate format can not be show for clients. Now how can I keep the modal displayed when I click submit button?

```
<a class='nav-link account-active' href='#' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my_account"></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="my_account" style='height: auto' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="flase">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs w-100" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item w-50">
                        <a href="#login" class="nav-link text-center active" data-toggle="tab">LOGIN</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item w-50">
                        <a href="#register" class="nav-link text-center" data-toggle="tab">SIGN UP</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content" style="font-size: 14px;">
                <div id="login"  class="tab-pane active" style='height: 550px'>
                    <form method='post' action=''>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center mt-4 mb-3" id="eModalLabel">WELCOME BACK!</h4>
                    <h6 class="text-center text-muted">Login to your account</h6>
                    <div class="error" id='signin_err'>{signin_err}</div>
                    <div class='section-input'>
                        <div class="mt-2">Email</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 my-2" name="" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class='section-input'>                     
                        <div class="mt-2">Password</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 my-2" name="">
                    </div>
                    <div class='section-input'>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 my-3" type="submit" name="signin_btn">LOGIN</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>

                        <div class="forgot text-center mb-3">forgot your password?</div>

                </div>
                <div id="register" class="tab-pane" style='height: auto'>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center mt-4 mb-3" id="eModalLabel" style='text-transform: uppercase;'>It's as easy as sunday morning</h4>
                    <h6 class="text-center text-muted">Sign up now</h6>

                    <div class='error' id='signup_err'>{signup_err}</div>

                    <div class='section-input' style="margin-top: 70px">

                        <div class="mt-2" id='signUp_name'>Name</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 my-2" name="name" autofocus >
                    </div>
                    <div class='section-input'>
                        <div class="mt-2" id='signUp_mail'>Email</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 my-2" name="mail" id='mail' >

                    </div>

                    <div class='section-input'>
                        <div class="mt-2" id='signUp_psd'>Password</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 my-2" name="psd" >
                    </div>

                    <div class='section-input'>
                        <div class="mt-2" id='confirm_psd'>Confirm password</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100 my-2" name="psd_cf" >
                    </div>



                    <div class='section-input'>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 my-3" style='height:48px;margin-bottom:100px;border-radius: 0' type="" name="signup_btn">SIGN UP</button>
                    </div>

                    <div style='height:70px'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any codes to provide?

Comment: You can start by providing some code and we will try to help you out, also try and debug your code to see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: How do you really expect someone to accurately answer your question given the information you have provided?

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your backend is being implemented, but based on your code, my guess is that your page is being refreshed every time you click submit because of the empty action. I see no other way that the modal will close.

You'll need to submit via AJAX if you want to display any validation without refreshing.

Comment: Thank you sir, your advice is useful. It's solved by Ajax